# Restrictions of Inserting Numbers Method

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

These are two similar questions from two different contests.

1. (AIME 2015) Call a permutation $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ quasi-increasing if $a_k \leq a_{k+1} + 2$ for each $1\leq k\leq n-1$.
   For example, $54321$ and $14253$ are quasi-increasing permutations of the integers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, but
   $45123$ is not. Find the number of quasi-increasing permutations of the integers $1, 2, . . . , 7$.

By inserting numbers one by one, the answer is $486$, which is the intended answer.

Let me explain the method used here:
Assume that the number of quasi-increasing permutations of the integers $1, 2, 3, ..., n$ be $A_n$, then obviously $A_1=1$, $A_2=2$, $A_3=6$, thus 4 can be inserted into the string of integers $1, 2, 3$ in only $3$ ways, so $A_4=3\times A_3=18$, and so do $5, 6, 7$, so $A_7=3\times 3\times 3\times A_4=486$

---

2. (SMO 2010 Open R1) Find the number of permutations $a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5a_6$ of the six integers from $1$ to $6$ such that for all $i$ from $1$ to $5$, $a_{i+1}$ does not exceed $a_i$ by $1$.

By inserting numbers one by one, the answer is $120$, which is not the intended answer.
By Inclusion-Exclusion, the answer is $309$, which is the intended answer.

I would like to ask what are the restrictions of this method for solving these similar problems?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "By inserting numbers one by one" and 'Inserting Numbers Method".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for $n$-step process where the first step can be done in $m_1$ ways, the second in $m_2$ ways, and so on up the the $n^\text{th}$ being doable in $m_n$ ways, the number of ways to complete the whole process is $$m_1\times m_2\times \dots \times m_n$$

Importantly, the number of ways to complete each step must not depend on which particular choices you made previously. If $m_3=7$ (say), there should always be three choices for the third step, regardless of what you chose in steps $1$ and $2$.

Let's see why this works for the AIME 2015 problem. A permutation can be built by inserting the numbers $1,2,\dots, n$ one at a time. $1$ can be inserted in one way, $2$ in two ways, $3$ in three ways. For each $k\in \{4,\dots,n\}$, when you try to insert $k$ into the previous permutation made up $\{1,\dots,k-1\}$, there are always three options: either at the end of the permutation, or just before $k-1$, or just before $k-2$. These are indeed always legal, regardless of the specific ordering of $\{1,\dots,k-1\}$, and no other options are allowed. We conclude that the number of ways is $1\times 2\times 3\times 3\times \dots \times 3=2\cdot 3^{n-2}$.

Why does this same idea not work for the SMO 2010 problem? Let's see. Just look at a small example, permutations of length $3$. There is only one valid permutation of length $2$ where $a_{k+1}\neq a_k+1$, namely $[2,1]$. There are two ways to insert $3$ into this while maintaining the property $a_{k+1}\neq a_k+1$, which would suggest that there are only two valid permutations of length $3$, namely $[3,2,1]$ and $[2,1,3]$. However, there is actually a third permutation that works, namely, $[1,3,2]$. How did we miss this? The problem is that our process would require first inserting $2$ after $1$, which seems illegal, then later inserting $3$ after $1$. Inserting the $3$ blocks the $2$ from the $1$, so the it turned out not be an illegal move. To summarize,

> the number of available moves depends on what choices were made later.

This shows that the number of moves at each step is *not* constant, so you cannot just multiply the number of ways to complete each step.